# Open and Collect Data from Multiple Files in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, stream, elixir

I am teaching myself Elixir for my research, and oftentimes my research requires opening several dozen or hundred text files, combining the data in these files, and manipulating the data. I am trying to figure out how I can open all the files I have in a directory and access the data in all these files. I would like to avoid using a for loop because to iterate through 100 files in a loop would be very slow. I think that the Stream module is ideal for my purposes, but I don't know quite how to use it.

Below, I have some test code. All it is supposed to do is open a bunch of files containing random numbers, convert the strings of numbers in the files to integers, and sort them. Everything works except the opening files part. You can see I tried to use the Path module, and this does succeed in finding all the files, but I don't know how to then pass that to the sort_num function in a usable way. Thanks for your help everyone!

```
defmodule OpenFiles do

  def file_open do
    Path.wildcard("numfiles/*.txt")
  end

  def sort_num do
    file_open
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.map(&String.strip/1)
    |> Stream.map(&String.to_integer/1)
    |> Enum.sort
  end 
end

IO.inspect OpenFiles.sort_num
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `File.stream!/3` function only works on one file at a time. If you are using the wildcard and collecting multiple files at once, it does not work the way you expect.

If you look at the return of `Path.wildcard/2`, you get a list of all files matched. something along the lines of

```
["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.txt"]
```

If you pass this into `File.stream!/3`, it tries to append all of these values together.

```
File.stream! ["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.txt"]
%File.Stream{line_or_bytes: :line, modes: [:raw, :read_ahead, :binary],
 path: "foo.txtbar.txtbaz.txt", raw: true}
```

As you can see, it thinks the path you are trying to access is `"foo.txtbar.txtbaz.txt"`, which is incorrect and all of the "paths" concatenated together.

In order to access all of these files, you are going to have to run each one on its own.

```
defmodule OpenFiles do
  def file_open do
    Path.wildcard("numfiles/*.txt")
  end

  def sort_num do
    file_open()
    |> Enum.map(fn file ->
      file
      |> File.stream!()
      |> Stream.map(&String.strip/1)
      |> Stream.map(&String.to_integer/1)
      |> Enum.take(1) # This only takes the first line. This may or may not be what you want.
    end)
    |> List.flatten()
    |> Enum.sort()
  end 
end
```

As you mentioned, if you have a lot of files (or large files), this could take a long time. However, you can mitigate this by using a parallel map implementation instead of the sequential `Enum.map/2`.

Comment: Really great and detailed answer! Thanks so much. Yes, I think a parallel map implementation will be my best bet.